# how to migrate AWS RDS MySql engine database to AWS serverless?

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-serverless

I'm running a development db in aws rds MySql engine. I've lots of testing data in this. Now I want to use aws serverless db, but I also want to copy the data from old rds instance to the serverless without dump.

[image: These are the two instances I'm working with right now]

Can I do this like taking snapshot of old rds and restore to serverless db? I tried to do this but have no luck.
Can anyone guide me to the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a snapshot and restoring to a Serverless cluster should work. If it does not, can you please share snapshots or CLI examples?